# Debian stretch upgrade

Tags: dependencies, debian, upgrade, kde-plasma

When I tried to upgrade Debian Jessie to stretch I got this:

```
marcin@marcin:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-plasma-desktop : Depends: plasma-desktop (>= 4:5.0.0) but 4:4.11.13-2 is to be installed
 plasma-workspace : Breaks: plasma-desktop (<= 4:5) but 4:4.11.13-2 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I fix these dependencies and what is wrong with 50unattended-upgrades file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-plasma-desktop plasma-workspace
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist
```

then finally update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you. My friend told me this yesterday and it had worked. But are you sure about removing 50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist file?